# Deserializing complex nested JSON into Scala objects

Tags: json, scala, serialization

Scala 2.12 here. I'm trying to use Lift-JSON to deserialize some JSON into a Scala object and am having trouble navigating the Lift API. **Please note: I'm not married to Lift-JSON**, any other working solution will be accepted so long as I don't have to bring any heavy/core Play dependencies into my project.

---

Here's the JSON file I'm trying to read:

```
{
  "fizz" : "buzz",
  "foo" : [
    "123",
    "456",
    "789"
  ],
  "bar" : {
    "whistle" : 1,
    "feather" : true
  }
}
```

Here's my Scala object hierarchy:

```
case class Bar(whistle : Integer, feather : Boolean)
case class MyConfig(fizz : String, foo : Array[String], bar : Bar)
```

And finally my best attempt at the codeup for this:

```
def loadConfig(configFilePath : String) : MyConfig = {
  val configJson = Source.fromFile(configFilePath)

  val parsedJson = parse(configJson.mkString)

  MyConfig(???)
}
```

I need validation in place so that if the JSON is not valid an exception is thrown. Any ideas how I can extract fields out of `parsedJson` and use them to set values for my `MyConfig` instance? And how to perform the validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `parsedJson.extract[MyConfig]`?  That is straight out of the [Extracting values](https://github.com/lift/framework/tree/master/core/json#extracting-values) documentation.  If you haven't already, you will need to specify an implicit reference to the default formats:

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
```

Comment: Thanks @Karl (+1) but adding that yields a compiler error: `/Users/myuser/workspace/myapp/src/main/scala/com/myapp/MyConfigLoader.scala:13: could not find implicit value for parameter formats: net.liftweb.json.Formats`